# Sharepoint online powershell usercustomactions scriptblock not working

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I want to add a warning message at the top of the SP online site. For that i tried UserCustomActions using powershell, code is running without error but not working. I tried to add ribbon control that is working. I have enabled the allow script option in the admin site. Below i included the code for reference.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

Function Add-ScriptLinkAction([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,[String]$ScriptBlock,[int]$Sequence)
{

    $action = $Context.Site.UserCustomActions.Add();
    $action.Location = "ScriptLink"
    <#
    if($ScriptSrc) {
        $action.ScriptSrc = $ScriptSrc
    }#>
    
    if($ScriptBlock) {
        $action.ScriptBlock = $ScriptBlock
    }
    $action.Sequence = $Sequence
    $action.Name = "title"
    $action.Title = "title"
    $action.Update()
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}

$siteUrl = 'https://stginfotechchennai.sharepoint.com/sites/ProductQualityReseachCenter'
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
# SPO credentials
$context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName username@domain.com

Add-ScriptLinkAction -Context $context -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Sequence 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

@Hemanth kumar,

SharePoint online modern UI does not support scriptlink User custom actions, toolbar items(CommandUI.Ribbon) and custom menu items(EditControlBlock) are still supported. For more details, you can refer to:

- [Customizing "modern" lists and libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries#user-custom-actions)

Based on the doc suggestion, you may need to turn to SPFx extension:

- http://www.luisevalencia.com/2017/06/08/injecting-javascript-with-sharepoint-framework-extensions-preview-azure-application-insights/
- https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-add-a-js-file-to-all-pages-in-a-spfx-modern-pages-using-sharepoint-framework-extension/
- https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss

BR